# Reflection: How to compare two objects from unkown type

Tags: java, database, reflection

I'm doing an application that do custom decision making. Let's say I have 4 tables: Documment, File, Task and Process. I'm working with JPA so every table is translated to an entity, a Java Class with variables.
A Process have many task, a task have a file associated and a file have many documments associated.
What I want to do is configure so I can compare an attribute in Task with another Attribute in Process.
For example:
I configure in a table Decision:

Attribute 1: Process Limit Date
Attribute 2: Task Actual Date
Operator: >

What I'm trying to do is on runtime know the valor of that variable to take some decisions.

And Now.
I have these methods:

```
public Object runGetter(Field field, Class o, Object instance) {
    for (Method method : o.getMethods()) {
        if ((method.getName().startsWith("get")) && (method.getName().length() == (field.getName().length() + 3))) {
            if (method.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(field.getName().toLowerCase())) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Method Name: " + method.getName());
                    return method.invoke(instance);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

After I search for the field in the class, I will run its getter and catch an Object in return. That's the Object I want to compare.
But I don't know what is that object so I did something like this for find it's type (which I save in the table):

```
public <T> T convertirObjeto(Object objetoAConvertir, Class<T> claseDestino) {
try {
    return claseDestino.cast(objetoAConvertir);
} catch(ClassCastException e) {
    return null;
}
```

That will return me something like String.class, Integer.class.

My idea was that I could do the first method, then call the second one sending the first method's return object and get in return an object.
So let's said I save an Integer. I wish to compare if Integer 1 is higher or lower than Integer 2. My theory (wish possibly is very stupid) said that I can do:

```
 if (convertirObjeto(obtenerValorAtributo(atributo1),Class.forName(atributo1.getTipoAtributo())) <convertirObjeto(obtenerValorAtributo(atributo2),Class.forName(atributo2.getTipoAtributo()))) {
```

Instead of just cast

```
(Integer) obtenerValorAtributo(atributo2)
```

But when I try to compare that the compiler throws the following error:

```
Bad Operand types for binary operator '<'
First type: CAP#1
Second Type: CAP#2
Where CAP#1, CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

I think, the compiler is trying to tell me: Sir, you don't know what these objects are, stop trying to burn me please.
My question are:

```
If(Is there a *easier* solution for my problem than all that reflection I'm trying to do?)
Else If(Is there a way to fix that problem so I could compare two variables from different classes searching in database its name, table and maybe type?)
```

**EDIT:** The question was edited asking for help for my full problem and not just for the solution I though.

Comment: Will the objects only be documents, just different types of documents?

Comment: Documents was an example. It can compare something from like 5 different tables. Let's say a formality, a process, a task, a file or a document.

Comment: So you want to be able to compare a task against a process? And what exactly are you trying to compare between them? It would be a lot easier to create an abstraction, for example, `ProgramItem` (bad name, just an example), which contains the state you wanna compare between each item (process, task, ect..). Or do you want to perform a particular compare action depending on what's being compared?

Comment: No, not a task and a process. I want to compare something like: ProcessLimitDate, with TaskDate. Both are Date attributes. But in the process I set the limit date for every task. And the same with integer values or string values.

Comment: Are `ProcessLimitDate` and `TaskDate` classes? Or are the types `Process` and `Task`, and you want to compare the `Date` states of them? Would be easier to understand if you included more code, and possibly shorten up your question (reformat it so others don't need to read so much)

Comment: I'm working with JPA. So Process and Task are entities. And these dates are variables in the entities.
I'm going to reformat the question.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName` returns a `Class<?>`. You need to cast it to the correct class type:

```
Integer first = convertObject(new Integer(5), (Class<Integer>) Class.forName("java.lang.Integer"));
Integer second = convertObject(new Integer(10), (Class<Integer>) Class.forName("java.lang.Integer"));

System.out.println(first < second);
```

This will allow the method to infer the generic type. Since `Class.forName` returns a `Class<?>` and not Class`, the`T` type in your method will not be infered to your class type unless you cast it first.

As for a better solution, I'm gonna be honest, I have no clue what you're trying to achieve with this. Check out [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as you are currently seeking help for what you think is a solution to the actual problem at hand, rather than seeking help for your ultimate goal

Comment: I edited the main question and add some information about the full problem, but I didn't wanted to ask that because that I feel that it would be something like: do my homework pls. But some help will be appreciated tho.